# Size to fit and then text alignment

Tags: swift

I’m using sizeToFit for a UILabel. After using that I want to align the text in the center. When I try to align it using the textAlignment property, the text doesn’t get aligned to the center. Can someone help me figure out how to align text horizontally in the center after calling sizeToFit?

Comment: To center the text, use NSTextAlignmentCenter. When the label needs to be resized to fit its content, sizeToFit is then used. The super view's center point is the last setting for the center property.

lable.textAlignment = .center
lable.sizeToFit()

After calling sizeToFit() on the label, you can center the text horizontally.